# I wants to read rows of gray scale Image into an array of integer for processing in Qt

Tags: qt, qimage, scanline

I have one Gray scale image, which I wants to read row by row and process( to find the median)
I created one QImage by loading the file. Then I used scanline(x) to read the row. But I am getting some wrong values( hope values should be 0-256). Scanline() gets the RGBA values I think. How to use this method for gray scale. Or any other solution please

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean wrong values? If you get RGBA(45, 45, 45, 255), that's gray. If you want a 0-255 value, then just read the red component only (for example).